# How to add data to Firebase Realtime Database using Asp.Net Mvc Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase-realtime-database, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a task management application using Asp.net MVC Core, and I am utilizing Firebase Realtime Database as the database.

```
 public async Task CreateJobList(JoblistModels joblistModels, string name) 
 {

     JoblistModels joblistModels1 = new JoblistModels();
     joblistModels1.JobListName = joblistModels.JobListName;
     joblistModels1.Time = DateTime.Now;

     // Firebase Client oluşturma
     client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
     var data = joblistModels1;
     string link = name + "/Joblist";
     // Firebase'e yeni veri ekleme
     PushResponse response = client.Push("Joblist",data);
     
     
     //data.JobListName = response.Result.name;
     //SetResponse setResponse = client.Set("/" + data.JobListName, data);
 }
```

The code works like this, but I `PushResponse Response = client.Push(name, data);`. I want it to work like this, but nothing is added to the database.

```
public async Task CreateJobList(JoblistModels joblistModels, string name) 
 {

     JoblistModels joblistModels1 = new JoblistModels();
     joblistModels1.JobListName = joblistModels.JobListName;
     joblistModels1.Time = DateTime.Now;

     // Firebase Client oluşturma
     client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
     var data = joblistModels1;
     string link = name + "/Joblist";
     // Firebase'e yeni veri ekleme
     PushResponse response = client.Push("Joblist",data);
     
     
     //data.JobListName = response.Result.name;
     //SetResponse setResponse = client.Set("/" + data.JobListName, data);
 }
my code
```

When I edit the code like this it doesn't work

```
public async Task CreateJobList(JoblistModels joblistModels, string name) 
 {

     JoblistModels joblistModels1 = new JoblistModels();
     joblistModels1.JobListName = joblistModels.JobListName;
     joblistModels1.Time = DateTime.Now;

     // Firebase Client oluşturma
     client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
     var data = joblistModels1;
     string link = name + "/Joblist";
     // Firebase'e yeni veri ekleme
     PushResponse response = client.Push(name,data);
     
     
     //data.JobListName = response.Result.name;
     //SetResponse setResponse = client.Set("/" + data.JobListName, data);
 }
```

usage libraries
Firabase.Database and FireSharp

Comment: You have three code snippets in your question, and I'm having a hard time seeing the difference between them. Please edit your question to include just the one code snippet that doesn't work, and include any error message your get - and the result of locally stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: in the code PushResponse response = client.Push("Joblist",data); field PushResponse response = client.Push(name, data); When I update as , no data is added to the database, only if I give a constant value, the value is added.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see what `JoblistModels` looks like, but in general Firebase only saves JSON type data. You'll want to try passing the data as a `Map`/`Dictionary` to see if that works.

Comment: I will try what you say

Comment: We decided to abandon the use of Firebase in our project. The entire infrastructure has been updated to align with the MSSQL database